# Custom route for record.save() in ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ember.js, ember-data

In ember ,  I have a model called "Post" .
 If i perform

```
 record.save()
```

on creating a post , by default it posts to my `/post` url in Rails(backend). This works in my case. But for future uses, how do i specify a custom route? Let's say I want to post this model to my backend to a route called

```
"/post/save"
```

How do i make `record.save()` in ember  to go to this route?

Comment: Checkout the adapter documentation

Comment: Can you provide me with a link? I read the documentation but i don't recall seeing the above usecase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adapters](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter/methods/urlForCreateRecord) in ember manage *how* a model communicates with remote data.  If you need to go outside of ember convention, you can create a  custom adapter for your model that can point actions to different places.

```
ember generate adapter model-name
```

In your case, you want to call `/post/save` instead of `/post` when you create a post. You would overload the method [`urlForCreateRecord`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter/methods/urlForCreateRecord?anchor=urlForCreateRecord):

```
urlForCreateRecord(modelName, snapshot) {
  return '/post/save';
}
```

Each url for an action (create, update, new, find, query) can be adjusted to fit your backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the adapter of your post model.

Given your case, you need to add:

```
urlForCreateRecord () {
    return this._super(...arguments) + '/save';
}
```

That url will only be used when the `save` method is creating the record (POST), when `save`ing already existing records (PATCH) you should use `urlForUpdateRecord`